# Is it possible to automatically bundle, minify and include my page specific Javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

For each of my views I have page specific javascript stored in a separate file, my naming convention results in that each js file always lives in the same place scripts/pagejs/controllername/viewname.js  Can I automatically include and minify these javascript files for each view?

I've already got so far in thinking and I can do it this way without bundling, I have a render tag in my cshtml page that looks in the scripts directory, I could replace this with one that looks in the bundles directory

```
<script src="/Bundles/pagejs/Account/Home.js"></script>
```

The bundling process should result in one bundle containing one javascript file (the bundling process here is only useful for the minification process)

Comment: You can certainly create a bundle per view, and use @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/controllerA/viewA") (assuming that is the convention you want to use for the bundles).
You might want to surround this @Scripts.Render call inside a section if you are using a layout page.
I didn't include this in an answer, because what you are mainly asking here is if you can have this convention automated, so you don't have to manually create a bundle per view, and reference it.
I don't really know how to achieve this, but you can have your view scripts minified if you want to go the manual route described above.

Comment: Thanks Raciel, I am a little bit new to bundling but I do know how to do it manually.  One thought I have just had is to run a minification tool on those js files as part of the automated build.  Then, look in that directory and if we're debug look for home.js & if its release then look for home.min.js  I haven't used a minifier before but I guess that's not too difficult.  However, it would be nicer if I didn't have to add another step in the automated build process and if I was able to use the same minifier.